# Why some links aren't found using beautiful soup

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup (bf4) to find all the links that refer to a pdf file on a given website page.

Here is the code I took away from GeeksForGeeks :

```
hermes_url = "https://finance.hermes.com/en/publications?type=19"

# Import libraries 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# URL from which pdfs to be downloaded 
url = hermes_url

# Requests URL and get response object 
response = requests.get(url) 

# Parse text obtained 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 


#result = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'document'})

# Find all hyperlinks present on webpage 
links = soup.find_all('a') 

i = 0

# From all links check for pdf link and 
# if present download file 

for link in links :
    print(link)

for link in links: 
    if ('.pdf' in link.get('href', [])):
        i += 1
        print("Downloading file: ", i) 

        # Get response object for link 
        response = requests.get(link.get('href')) 

        # Write content in pdf file 
        pdf = open("pdf"+str(i)+".pdf", 'wb') 
        pdf.write(response.content) 
        pdf.close() 
        print("File ", i, " downloaded") 

print("All PDF files downloaded")
```

The issue is that as we can see by printing the links found, only the "static" parts of the page (the categories on the top and on the bottom) are taken into account and none of the links in the main part (where there are the pdf files) are analyzed which means I end up with no pdf downloaded.
Does somebody know how could I change that and get access to all the links on the page ?

Comment: The links are generated dynamically by `JavaScript`. In other words, you won't scrape that with `bs4`. Try exploring `selenium` or see if there's an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://finance.hermes.com/en/publications/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
soup = Bs(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

li=soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'document'})
[i['href']  for i in li if i['href'].endswith('pdf')]
```

you may need to specify the `webdriver.chrome('path')`.
`time.sleep` lets you to wait till the page loads.
After waiting for the specified time we'll get the source of the page using `beautifulsoup`.
from the source we can extract all the `a` tags with the class `document`.It returns all the `a` tags. But we are interested in `.pdf` so the last list coprehension just gets the `href` attributes of `a` tags which ends with `pdf`.
This will just load the `9`pdfs for the rest you need to make selenium to click on loadmore